Restoring the set of $x$ and $y$ from the result of addition: $s = f(x) + f(y)$
Let $x$ and $y$ be n-bit integers.
Find a single-parameter function $f$ (which outputs $k$-bit numbers) such that the set of $x$ and $y$ can be calculated from the result of addition $s = f(x) + f(y)$. (The ordering of $x$ and $y$ does not matter. The addition is commutative, so it would have been impossible to restore the original ordering.)
What is the minimal bit length $k$ among such functions?
The lower bound for $k$ is $2 \cdot n$ which corresponds to concatenation of $x$ and $y$. If $y$ is bit shifted, then addition does not mangle the bits of $x$ and $y$, so $x$ and $y$ can be restored. However bit shifting $y$ cannot be a solution to this problem since it's only applied to $y$ while we need a symmetrical solution where same function $f$ is applied to both $x$ and $y$.
The upper bound for $k$ is $2^{n}$ which corresponds to $f(x) = 2^{x}$. Each number maps to a certain bit position and the addition operation preserves that information making restoring $x$ and $y$ possible.
(With randomized $f$ it's possible to produce pretty short representations that are very likely to survive addition. But I seek normal deterministic functions here.)
Update:
I wonder whether this problem has some relation to the Golomb_ruler problem (but a modification where all pairwise sums (not differences) must be distinct). If we have a set of $2^n$ numbers such that all pairwise sums are distinct, then $f$ can map each $x$ to one of those numbers and after the results are summed, the original set of numbers can be recovered from the sum.

That's OK. I do not care about the ordering. I only care about the set of the two numbers. I apologize for not explicitly specifying that fact.

I fully understand that recovering the argument ordering from a commutative/symmetrical operation is impossible, so it was never my intention to ask for that. I'm interested in recovering the [unordered] set of the arguments. (For example, to apply some other commutative function to them.)

Is $+$ regular addition, or modulo $2$? For the later, $f(x) + f(x) = 0$ and it's impossible to distinguish say $(0, 0)$ from $(1, 1)$.

If it's regular addition, standard probabilistic argument shows that if $k > 4n / (3 - \log_2 3) \approx 2.83n$, then there is such $f$. Is it of interest, or do you need an explicit construction?

@YvesDaoust I'm not sure I understand you. My question specifies a function that satisfies the requirements: $f(x)=2^x$ and my question mainly asks whether there are functions that are significantly better (less output bits). I do not understand why what I ask is considered impossible when I've provided a solution.

@mihaild $+$ is regular integer addition. (Although modulo $2^k$ would be interesting as well). A solution where $k$ has linear relation to $n$ is really great and intriguing. Can you please point me to the right direction?

(no proof of minimality, and likely can do significantly better, but still linear bound; also, worse than I wrote in comment, as I initially forgot the case when some arguments are the same)
Let $f$ be random function $\{0,1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}^k$ (so that $P(f(x)_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x, i$, and these events are mutually independent).
Call tetrad $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ bad if $f(x_1) + f(y_1) = f(x_2) + f(y_2)$ but $\{x_1,y_1\} \neq \{x_2, y_2\}$. What's probability (wrt random choice of $f$) of bad tetrad to exist?
There are several possibilities, depending if all arguments are different, or some are the same.

If all $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ are different, then all values of $f$ are indepentent, and $P(f(x_1) + f(y_1) = f(x_2) + f(y_2)) = \left(\frac 38\right)^k$. There are at most $2^{4n}$ such tetrads, so probability of having at least one bad tetrad of such type is at most $2^{4n}\left(\frac 38\right)^k$.

If at least two values among $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ are the same:

if $x_1 = y_1 \neq x_2$, we need $f(x_2) = f(x_1)$, which has probability $\frac{1}{2^k}$
similarly for cases $x_1 = y_1 \neq y_2$, $x_2 = y_2 \neq x_1$ and $x_2 = y_2 \neq y_1$
finally, when $x_1 \neq y_1$, $x_2 \neq y_2$, we have wlog $x_1 = x_2$, $y_1 \neq y_2$ and for tetrad to be bad we need $f(y_1) = f(y_2)$, which again has probability $\frac{1}{2^k}$.



There are at most $2^{3n+2}$ tetrads with at least two values being the same, thus probability of having at least one bad such tetrad is at most $\frac{2^{3n + 2}}{2^k}$.
Now, if $k > 3n + 3$, then probability for each type is less than $\frac{1}{2}$, and so probability of having a bad tetrad of any type is less than $1$. So with positive probability $f$ has no bad tetrads - in particular, there exists a function that has no bad tetrads.
